# Combining Indices of Two Sorted Lists to Form a Third SuperSorted List

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `['AAPL', 'MMM', 'AMAT']` and `['AMAT', 'AAPL', 'MMM']` and I want to create a third list based on the positions of each string in its respective list.

For example: 
`AAPL` ranks 1st + 2nd = total 3, `MMM` ranks 2nd and 3rd = total 5, `AMAT` ranks 1st and 3rd = total 4.

Final list would be (by decreasing cumulative position) `['AAPL', 'AMAT', 'MMM']`.

I don't even know where to begin with this.

Comment: How should ties be handled?

Comment: I don't think there will be ties. The lists are very long. But if there is, the most efficient solution would be best. It doesn't matter which comes first in the event of a tie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take one and do sort it by cumulative position.

```
>>> a, b = ['AAPL', 'MMM', 'AMAT'], ['AMAT', 'AAPL', 'MMM']
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: a.index(x) + b.index(x))
['AAPL', 'AMAT', 'MMM']
```

Comment: @Kasramvd If they could differ, then surely their example would show that and they'd specify how to treat that.

Comment: For this, the items are always going to strings. How does this sort function hold up with lots of elements--on the scale of 1000s?

Comment: @345243lkj Try it?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Late follow up: is there any easy modification to print out the list with a sum of that rank? Something like `['AAPL' 3, 'AMAT 4, 'MMM' 5]`

Comment: @345243lkj Sorry, I don't understand that format, especially why there's no `'` after `AMAT`.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity, however I figured it out! Thanks for all help with the original question!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dictionary in order to save the items with sum of their indices, then create the expected list based on indices:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> 
>>> for (ind1, j), (ind2, t) in zip(enumerate(a), enumerate(b)):
...     d[j] += ind1
...     d[t] += ind2
...  
>>> sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda x: d[x])
['AAPL', 'AMAT', 'MMM']
```

If lists don't have same length you can use `itertools.zip_longet` (in python2 `izip_longest`)in order to `zip` the enumerate objects.

Comment: Or you could just `enumerate` and loop over the two lists separately instead of any sort of `zip`ping.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, if the readability is more important than performance.

Comment: I don't see any way performance would be hurt by looping over the lists separately.

Comment: How about `enumerate(zip(a, b))`?

Comment: I like this ... sort of. It's almost Perl-like in its obscurity.

Comment: @user2357112 basically  `zip` will perform slightly better than, regular loops.

Comment: @user2357112 yeah, in this case it seems loops performs slightly better but I think it might be because of the enumerates, and the lengths. I'm testing with larger lists, and one more thing I didn't consider the fact that loops are not nested!